# Open a text file and let it update itself

Tags: files, monitoring, tail

How can I open a text file and let it update itself? Similar to the way `top` works.

I want to open a log file and watch it update itself on the fly.

I have just tried:

```
$ tail error.log
```

But just realised, that it just shows you the lines in the log file.

I am using RHEL 5.10

Comment: Use `tail -f error.log`

Comment: Ah, so `tail` is the correct way to use it? Wow, I really didn't think I could use that. I was expecting a much longer expression.

Comment: FYI, while tail *is* the tool for the job, literally `open a text file and let it update itself` can be achived with `watch cat filename`.

Comment: See the [tag:tail] tag here

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You're looking for `tail -f error.log` (from `man tail`):

```
   -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --fol‐
          low=descriptor are equivalent
```

That will let you watch a file and see any changes made to it.

Comment: And this won't use up much resources?

Comment: @Kevdog777 not really no. Presumably, it just re-opens the file every few seconds to update it. This is the classic way of doing what you want though.

Comment: @terdon, it only reopens (may reopen) with `-F`. With `-f` it just reads every second. It's like a `while cat; do sleep 1; done < file`. See `inotail` on Linux for a more _reactive_ tail (uses `inotify` to know when the file is being modified).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I am sure its a lot more efficient than that. I would bet it use select or poll to see if the fd is readable and then sleep until there is data available on the fd. Though I could be totally wrong.

Comment: @LokiAstari, you can't get much more efficient that a `read` system call every second. A "read" `select` or `poll` on a regular file would always return true since a `read()` never blocks on a regular file, so wouldn't work. Having said that, GNU `tail` now uses `inotify` on Linux, so `inotail` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 28):

#### Use "less" instead of "tail" for scrollback and search

You can use `tail -f error.log` or, better: `tail -F error.log`.

But if you want to scroll back in the file, that's not very useful.

With

```
less +F error.log
```

you get the function of `tail -f`,
but can  **interrupt** the reading of new input with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Then, you are in the normal `less` mode,
where you can **scroll back** to see what you may have missed with <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>
Also, you can read long log file lines without wrapping, using <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

#### Search, and show only matching lines

You can also search for regular expressions with <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd> for backward, <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> for next/previous.

Very interesting for log files is that you can **hide** all non-matching lines for a search with <kbd>&</kbd>, **filtering** out only the matches.

#### Keys on command line

With <kbd>F</kbd> inside of `less`, you **continue** the `tail -f`-like mode.
The `+` in the command line `less +F` means "press these keys directly after starting less".

So we used keypress <kbd>F</kbd> at startup, which is described as:

```
F  Scroll  forward,  and  keep trying to read when the end of file is
   reached.  Normally this command would be used when already at  the
   end  of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file which
   is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar  to
   the "tail -f" command.)
```

---

See also [`multitail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/multitail.1.html) if you need to watch more than one log file.

Comment: Thanks, but `tail -f error.log` is perfect for what I need. The log file only gets updated every hour, so is sufficient for my use :-)

Comment: Make sure to remember it for next time ;)

Comment: `most` also has a `tail -f` mode with `F`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas right, thanks! Hmmm... I remember someone thanked me for mentioning `most` a while ago... and I forgot it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But then, `most` does not seem to have the less filter feature `&` to show only matching lines? A useful feature in log files, usually.

Comment: Wow, the `&` trick is a gem! Thanks! `F` is cool too!

Answer (score 7):

Use `-f` option with `tail`:

> -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
>          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent

Or use `F` command inside `less`:

```
   F      Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally this command would be used when already at the end of the file.  It is a way to mon‐
          itor the tail of a file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behavior is similar to the "tail -f" command.)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers before me, you can also type something like `tail -25f error.log` if you want the command line to display **only the last 25 lines of the file**. I've found found this to be particularly useful, and I haven't seen it mentioned here yet.